# How to pass values from HTML controls to ASP.NET server?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I like to implement in my page functions which allow user to read and modify data, and save this data to XML file

I able to read data from xml, display on page, and save data to file, i not able to pass, entered by User data, from html page to function in ASP.NET Controler (SaveConfigurationToFile)

HTML part:

```
<html>
 <table class="table" style="text-align: left; width: 198px; height: 60px;"
           border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><text name="Day">Poniedziałek</text></td>
                <td><text name="Day">Wtorek</text></td>
                <td><text name="Day">Środa</text></td>
                <td><text name="Day">Czwartek</text></td>
                <td><text name="Day">Piątek</text></td>
                <td><text name="Day">Sobota</text></td>
                <td><text name="Day">Niedziela</text></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input id="MondayStart" type="time" class="form-control" name="Start"  value="@ViewBag.MondayStart"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input id="MondayEnd" type="time" class="form-control" name="End" value="@ViewBag.MondayEnd"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="submit" value="Zapisz" class="btn btn-default"> @Html.ActionLink("Zapisz", "SaveConfigurationToFile")</button>
    <br>
</html>
```

'''''''''''''

Controler part:

''''''''''''

```
public ActionResult SaveConfigurationToFile(IFormCollection collection)
        {  
            PortalConfiguration dataToSave = new PortalConfiguration();
            dataToSave.SaveConfigurationData("string","string");
            return View();
        }
```

I like to have possibility to pass data entered in table to function SaveConfigurationToFile

Comment: It's not clear to me which part you're stuck at. Your controller is accepting an IFormCollection, yet you've shown no attempt to get the data from that object. You've also not describe creating any sort of model to take advantage of MVC's model binding capabilities - something any basic ASP.NET MVC tutorial should cover. Can you explain exactly what you're stuck on?

Comment: I'd say to start you need to add <form></form> tags surrounding the input elements that need to send data to the server. I'd also recommend creating a view model class to represent this data in your view.  You can then use Model Binding to have a strongly typed object to work with in your controller.

Comment: Please look for any tutorial for basic understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I use Your advice and i create model:

```
public class ConfigurationData
    {
        //Model for configuration page to be saved in xml
        [Key]
        public string MondayStart { get; set; }
        public string MondayEnd { get; set; }
        public string TuesdayStart { get; set; }
        public string TuesdayEnd { get; set; }
        public string WednesdayStart { get; set; }
        public string WednesdayEnd { get; set; }
        public string ThursdayStart { get; set; }
        public string ThursdayEnd { get; set; }
        public string FridayStart { get; set; }
        public string FridayEnd { get; set; }
        public string SaturdayStart { get; set; }
        public string SaturdayEnd { get; set; }
        public string SundayStart { get; set; }
        public string SundayEnd { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string phone { get; set; }
    }
```

Then based on model i create View :

```
 <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="SaveConfigurationToFile">
        <table class="table" style="text-align: left; width: 198px; height: 60px; margin-left:10px"
               border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><text name="Day">Poniedziałek</text></td>
                    <td><text name="Day">Wtorek</text></td>
                    <td><text name="Day">Środa</text></td>
                    <td><text name="Day">Czwartek</text></td>
                    <td><text name="Day">Piątek</text></td>
                    <td><text name="Day">Sobota</text></td>
                    <td><text name="Day">Niedziela</text></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>

                    <td>
                        <div class="form-group" >
                            <input asp-for="MondayStart" class="form-control" type="time" value="@ViewBag.MondayStart" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="MondayStart" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input asp-for="ThursdayStart" class="form-control" type="time" value="@ViewBag.ThursdayStart" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="TuesdayStart" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input asp-for="WednesdayStart" class="form-control" type="time" value="@ViewBag.WednesdayStart"/>
                            <span asp-validation-for="WednesdayStart" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input asp-for="TuesdayStart" class="form-control" type="time" value="@ViewBag.TuesdayStart" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="ThursdayStart" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input asp-for="FridayStart" class="form-control" type="time" value="@ViewBag.FridayStart" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="FridayStart" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input asp-for="SundayStart" class="form-control" type="time" value="@ViewBag.SundayStart"/>
                            <span asp-validation-for="SundayStart" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input asp-for="SundayStart" class="form-control" type="time" value="@ViewBag.SundayStart" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="SundayStart" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input asp-for="MondayEnd" class="form-control" type="time" value="@ViewBag.MondayEnd"/>
                            <span asp-validation-for="MondayEnd" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input asp-for="TuesdayEnd" class="form-control" type="time" value="@ViewBag.TuesdayEnd"/>
                            <span asp-validation-for="TuesdayEnd" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input asp-for="WednesdayEnd" class="form-control" type="time" value="@ViewBag.WednesdayEnd" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="WednesdayEnd" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input asp-for="ThursdayEnd" class="form-control" type="time" value="@ViewBag.ThursdayEnd"/>
                            <span asp-validation-for="ThursdayEnd" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input asp-for="FridayEnd" class="form-control" type="time" value="@ViewBag.FridayEnd"/>
                            <span asp-validation-for="FridayEnd" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input asp-for="SaturdayEnd" class="form-control" type="time" value="@ViewBag.SaturdayEnd"/>
                            <span asp-validation-for="SundayEnd" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input asp-for="SundayEnd" class="form-control" type="time" value="@ViewBag.SundayEnd" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="SundayEnd" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input asp-for="email" class="form-control" type="email" value="@ViewBag.email" />
            <span asp-validation-for="email" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input asp-for="phone" class="form-control" type="tel" value="@ViewBag.phone" />
            <span asp-validation-for="phone" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" value="Zapisz" class="btn btn-default"> Zapisz zmiany</button>
    </form>
```

And then i was able to get data in code behind :

```
public ActionResult SaveConfigurationToFile(ConfigurationData model)
        {

            PortalConfiguration dataToSave = new PortalConfiguration();
            dataToSave.SaveConfigurationData(model.MondayStart, model.MondayEnd,model.ThursdayStart,model.TuesdayEnd, model.WednesdayStart,model.WednesdayEnd,
                model.ThursdayStart,model.ThursdayEnd,model.FridayStart, model.FridayEnd, model.SaturdayStart, model.SaturdayEnd, model.SundayStart,model.SundayEnd,
                model.email, model.phone);
            return Redirect("../Home/Configuration");
        }
```

Now working ok